# facebook like box plug-in error

Tags: web, facebook-likebox

Good afternoon.  i am working on implementing the facebook like box into website.  i have generated the code on this facebook page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

which generated the following code:  `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FStripeworX%2F203309163017772&amp;width=292&amp;height=300&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

The issue is when i test the page in internet explorer i receive the following error:

Cannot find
'file://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FStripeworX%2F203309163017772&width=292&height=300&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true'.  Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.

thank you, any information that can be provided is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an `http` or `https` at the beginning of the `scr` attribute of the `iframe`.
It appears that you are doing some sort of local development and the ommision of the protocol makes your platform believe that the source of the `iframe` is a local file.